# How to add another single anonymous type to LINQ query?

Tags: c#, linq

I want to add an item to linq result. Here is my initial query.

```
var groups = from gr in monitors.groupiddeviceids
                 where gr.device.customerID == customerID
                 group gr by gr.grouping.GroupName into g
                 select new { Group = g.Key, Devices = g.Count() };
```

I want to put this to a gridview datasource like this:

```
gvGroups.DataSource = groups.ToList();
```

But beforehand I want to add one more row to it. The row is of {string, int} format. The row I want to add should read {"Unassigned", 14}

How do I add an item to linq list of annonymous types?

Comment: Like groups.ToList().Add(new { Group = "UnAssigned", Devices = 14 }); gvGroups.DataSource = groups; ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240412/add-an-anonymous-object-to-an-anonymous-list

Answer (score 6):

You can put this anonymous type in an array and use `Concat`:

```
var unassigned = new[] { new { Group = "Unassigned", Devices = 14 } };
gvGroups.DataSource = groups.Concat(unassigned).ToList();
```

If you want it to be the first item: `unassigned.Concat(groups).ToList();`

If it's actually a database query, that might cause some troubles. Then *materialize* the query first, for example with `ToList`:

```
var groupList = groups.ToList();
groupList.Add(unassigned);
gvGroups.DataSource = groupList;
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work like that, thanks!

```
gvGroups.DataSource = groups.ToList().Concat(new[] { new { Group = "Unassigned", Devices = 14 } });
```

Comment: I've edited my answer to take that into account. I would not use `groups.ToList().Concat(..).ToList()` since that is unnecessary. Use a single `ToList` + `List.Add`.